# Discord Bot isn't responding

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots

For some reason, the basic `ping pong` command isn't working. I copied and pasted it from a website, but I am not sure what is wrong with it.

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
    const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
    client.login('hidden')



client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const { commandName } = interaction;

    if (commandName === 'ping') {
        interaction.reply('Pong.');
    }

});
```

There is no log error which makes it weirder. I know it is connecting because the bot appears online when I do a `node index.js` in the cmd panel.

Comment: does your console show "Ready!"?

Comment: And does your interaction reach its event handler?

Comment: yes it shows ready. When I type in !ping it doesn't respond with anything which is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I recommend that you fix the indentation at the beginning and move the `client.login` call to the end, as that's how the `discord.js` docs do it.

Additionally, are you sure you're using Discord.js v13? These events were added in v13, so if you run it with Discord.js v12, your bot will run, but your functions will never be called.

Otherwise, your code looks good (to me), but I'm not an expert.

Comment: mmm I thought I had v13? I'll double check

Comment: Well I can't figure out what version of discord.js it is. All I know is I ran basic install so it should be the current version.

Comment: Oh and I moved the login

Comment: in the `package.json`, under `dependencies` you will find the `discord.js` key and its value would be its version, please let us know the version you're using

Comment: "discord.js": "^13.3.0",

Comment: Ok so the only way for not showing (or responding with) anything is that the line `if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;` is triggered, you said you just copied that code from some website, did you also included some commands? Sounds like a stupid question, but if you haven't registered any command your bot won't recognize any interaction to be a command and the  `interaction.isCommand()` method will always return false

Comment: @tquigg96 Huh... that implies that `discord.js` is indeed installed as `13.3.0` or higher... do you happen to have a globally installed version of Discord (`npm i -g discord.js`)? If so, I'd uninstall that and then reinstall it locally (`npm i discord.js`). Also, make sure you have a `package-lock.json`. I'm willing to bet that you do, but just in case. Otherwise, I'm really not sure what's happening.

Comment: @Nick I just assumed that, but yeah, I can tell that would be an issue.

Comment: Ok so if you added some commands can you post a snippet of a command that should be executed?

Comment: Adding onto @Nick's statement -- if you can't do that, could you alternatively publish the code on GitHub for us to see?

Comment: @tquigg96 Can you post a snippet of your commands or publish your code to GitHub so we can assist in solving the problem?

Comment: I managed to get this to work. I am not sure but I did.